# Internal SATA drive from a MacBook Pro no being recognized when connected via an external USB drive

Tags: hard-drive, mac, mount

I had a 2012 MacBook Pro with an [OWC Data Doubler](https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/internal_storage/Data_Doubler) instead of the SuperDrive. My 2012 died and I bought a 2016 MacBook Pro. I removed the drive (a 1TB WD hard disk drive) from my old 2012 MacBook Pro to get some data from it by connecting to an external USB enclosure but I can't seem yo mount it.

Does anyone know what the problem might be? and/or how to solve it?

Here is a screenshot of disk utility:

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the system information on the device:

[image]

Comment: Is it being recognised as the correct drive/enclosure type? I wasn't aware the seagate backup plus had a 'plug-in' drive option.

Comment: @Tetsujin I took an old Seagate enclosure apart and attached my own HDD to it.

Comment: My bet is the enclosure is messing with the format, hiding it behind its own format.[They change the (apparent) block size, I think] Get a generic one meant for dropping spare drives in, instead.

Comment: @Tetsujin I had a suspicion that the enclosure might have been messing with it. I will buy a mounting encloser tomorrow and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Way late to the party and you've probably already resolved this, but whenever I have HD problems, I cut out the enclosure and use a [SATA-USB adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0758RP5V8).

If it still wont mount, you can use a data recovery tool, like [Disk Drill](https://www.cleverfiles.com/), which you can try for free and I wound up buying, or [Disk Warrior](https://www.alsoft.com/DiskWarrior/), which you have to buy outright. Using the former, I managed to recover about 85% of the mkv files I had stored on an actual Seagate BUP Slim (never again). Disclaimer: I'm not an employee or paid shill for any of the companies mentioned.

Good luck,
MB